# How do I make change the number format for information inside of my cardview?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am completing a project for my college class, but I am stuck on how to change the format for the information in my card view. I need it to be in the currency format, but it is in decimal form. I have tried multiple things but it hasn't worked.

here is the code in my custom adapter:

[image]

```
class MyAdapter(private val myDataset: ArrayList<Fillup>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>()
{

    class MyViewHolder(val cardView: CardView) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(cardView) {
        val textGallons = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textGallons)
        val textCost = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textCost)
        val textMiles = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textMiles)
        val textDate =itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textDate)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyAdapter.MyViewHolder {
        val aCardView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.card_one, parent, false) as CardView
        return MyViewHolder(aCardView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.textGallons.text = myDataset[position].gallons.toString()
        holder.textCost.text = myDataset[position].cost.toString() //This is what needs to change
        holder.textMiles.text =  myDataset[position].odo.toString()
        holder.textDate.text = myDataset[position].date.toString()
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = myDataset.size
}
```

Comment: Which text do you need formatted differently? How is it formatted now? Show an example screenshot. And explain how you want it formatted instead.

Comment: You probably need to use [`NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getCurrencyInstance()) to get a formater that will display currency the way you want instead of calling `toString()`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I've uploaded the image and commented next to the code

Comment: What do you want it to show instead?

Comment: Something like "$25" @Code-Apprentice

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the currency you can round it off using the following Math Functions.

```
float i = 3.2f;
float j = 3.8f;
Math.round(i); // output =3, since the decimal point is below 5
Math.round(j); // output = 4, since the decimal point is above 5

float k = 7.3f;
Math.ceil(k); // output = 8
Math.floor(k); // output = 7
```

So your code point of view Math functions that will suit to you if you want to round it off in incremental way. You code will look like something -

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.textGallons.text = myDataset[position].gallons.toString()
        holder.textCost.text = "$"+ String.format("%.2f", myDataset[position].cost) //Check this 
        holder.textMiles.text =  myDataset[position].odo.toString()
        holder.textDate.text = myDataset[position].date.toString()
    }
```

Or you can use other Math function based on your requirement.

Comment: This only works if the OP desires to display whole dollar amounts. Most likely, they want to display currencies to two decimal places.

Comment: String.format("%.2f", myDataset[position].cost) to get the decimal value updto 2 points

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get a currency symbol in your output is to just prepend it:

```
holder.textCost.text = "$" + myDataset[position].cost.toString()
```

For a homework assignment, this is probably sufficient. However, in a "real world" environment where your app is used in many countries, you should use a Locale object to be able to format with the proper currency symbol.